# ExtJS 4 Highlight values in grid that matches word in textfield

Tags: extjs, grid, highlight

I saw a similar post regarding this topic, but in this case I am having problems with the implementation, so I wonder to know if somebody could help me with this.

I have a grid panel and a textfield,both components of Sencha ExtJS 4.2.

I created a handler method that will receive the textfield value and process as follows:

```
markTextInGrid: function(searchFieldValue) {
    var me = this,
        tktListGrid = this.getTicketListGrid(),
        tktListGridStore = tktListGrid.getStore(),
        tktListGridView = tktListGrid.getView();

    tktListGridStore.each(function(record, idx) {
        try {
            var td = Ext.fly(me.tktListGridView.getNode(idx)).down('td'),
            cell, matches, cellHTML;

            while(td) {
                 cell = td.down('.x-grid-cell-inner');
                 matches = cell.dom.innerHTML.match(me.tagsRe);
                 cellHTML = cell.dom.innerHTML.replace(me.tagsRe, me.tagsProtect);

                 // populate indexes array, set currentIndex, and replace wrap matched string in a span
                 cellHTML = cellHTML.replace(searchFieldValue, function(m) {
                    return '<span class="' + me.matchCls + '">' + m + '</span>';
                 });
                 // restore protected tags
                 Ext.each(matches, function(match) {
                    cellHTML = cellHTML.replace(me.tagsProtect, match); 
                 });
                 // update cell html
                 cell.dom.innerHTML = cellHTML;
                 td = td.next();
             }
        } catch (e) {}



    });

}
```

I used a try-catch because, for some reason, I'm not always able to use "`down`" on the `Ext.fly` line. Sometimes it returns "undefined" but not sure why. In the example of LKiveSearchGrid seems like it always works, but for my case is not the same.

I defined the following components:

```
    tagsRe: /<[^>]*>/gm,

    tagsProtect: '\x0f',

    matchCls: 'x-livesearch-match',
```

I tried that piece of code but it is not highlighting the words in the grid.

Could somebody give me a hand with this please? I'll keep on researching.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using ?

Comment: What about this: create `var myTextFieldValue`, update it on textfield value change, add `renderer` to needed / all grid columns and in renderer compare `myTextFieldValue` and cell value (make sure that `myTextFieldValue` visible within renderer scope), when needed run grid's `doLayout()` so renderer do its job?

Comment: @JChap I'm using ExtJS 4.2. Thanks for the suggestion Sergey, I'll try this approach now and update the post as soon as I have something. Thanks!